# Kendo grid hierarchy from two html tables

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I have two tables with the following ID's `wage-table` and `wage-sub-table`.  They are HTML tables that need to have the sub table in the kendo hieracrhy.  This is what I have for my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var grid = $("#wage-table").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            pageSize: 15
        },
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        filterable: true,
        groupable: true,
        scrollable: false,
        resizable: true,
        detailInit: detailInit
    }).data("kendoGrid");

});
function detailInit(e) {
    $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            pageSize: 15
        },
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        filterable: true,
        groupable: true,
        scrollable: false,
        resizable: true
    });
}
```

How do I make it so the subtables data is rendered in the nested hierarchy table?

Comment: This appears to be pure JS to drive Kendo: why the ASP.NET and ASP.NET-MVC tags?

Comment: the tables are already rendered and you're converting them to kendo grids?

Comment: Correct they start as regular tables and the JS makes them into the grids